# Are there any Verizon smartphones that work in Israel?

Tags: cellphones, israel, communication

I know all the new 4G phones have GSM radios, but I heard that many (or maybe even all) of Verizon's smartphones make it so certain capabilities - specifically, data - don't work with international carriers, even if the phone is unlocked. Are there any smartphones (other than the iPhone) that would work as if it hadn't been tied to Verizon originally? I'm due for an upgrade and I'm planning to spend a lot of time in Israel.

Comment: If you're due for an upgrade, that usually means your contract is expiring. So why stick with Verizon?

Comment: Not a bad question, but unfortunately I'm on a family plan and everyone else wants to stick with Verizon... So I'm stuck.

Comment: If you plan to spend a lot of time in Israel, there's a good chance that you'd be better off with a different carrier, which would allow you to use the same phone in the U.S. and in Israel; even if that means you'd no longer get the Verizon family discount. But there are many factors to consider, and most of them have nothing to do with traveling :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to have to dig really deep into the specs of the phone to answer your question.

The issue is not the features themselves but the frequency spectrum on which these features are available.

You can look at:

- [GSM Frequency Bands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSM_frequency_bands)
- [UMTS Frequency Bands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UMTS_frequency_bands)

to see what is typically available in Israel.  From experience: IPhone 4S from AT&T works like a charm in Israel for both Data and Voice.  As far as I know GSM Voice Frequencies used in Israel are: 800(old, possibly decommissioned), 900, 1800, which IPhone and most Androids support.  The rest you will have to find out.

Now if you wanted to use CDMA, like Verizon does in Israel, roaming doesn't work on Cellcom's network as far as last information I have.

Answer (score 1):

Last I checked my Verizon CDMA phone worked in Israel. I was receiving telephone calls on my New York number. (Ouch that's expensive!)

Telecom is a GSM provider.

Pelephone was and may still be a CDMA provider